# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating memory game. I want to flip cards (divs) to make it more realistic. For fliping I am using [THIS](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) plugin. problem is that card flipping is not working. I got this error from console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined
```

You can see my code here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E2mWT/)

EDIT 1:

Full error log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined VM24:1
(anonymous function) VM24:1
m.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.m.each jquery.min.js:2
$.fn.flip VM24:1
OpenCard mem.js:94
m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
r.handle
```

This function use flip() function of included Jquery Flip plugin:

```
function OpenCard() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    if ($("#" + id + " img").is(":hidden")) {
        $(Source + " div").unbind("click", OpenCard);

        $("#" + id + " img").flip();

        if (ImgOpened == "") {
            BoxOpened = id;
            ImgOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
            }, 300);
        } else {
            CurrentOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            if (ImgOpened != CurrentOpened) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#" + id + " img").flip();
                    $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").flip();
                    BoxOpened = "";
                    ImgOpened = "";
                }, 400);
                Counter-=10;
                wrong.play();
            } else {
                $("#" + id + " img").parent().css("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").parent().css("disabled", "disabled");
                ImgFound++;
                BoxOpened = "";
                ImgOpened = "";
                Counter+=100;
                correct.play();
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
            }, 400);
        }
        $("#counter").html("" + Counter);

        if (ImgFound == ImgSource.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert ("Your score is "+Counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it

Comment: The error is somewhere else. Look for `foo.direction` where foo is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the settings object:

```
$("#" + id + " img").flip({direction: 'lr'});
```

You can get some examples in the [plugin page](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Salem. I tried that code before and it's not working in my case.

Comment: Are you sure? I have run your code and that's the only problem I found (if you are trying with the fiddle you gave, the link to `flip` library is wrong)

Comment: can you please give me a link of your jsFiddle? I tried and it's not working. Did you include other libs beside jquery and flip plugin?

Comment: Also I tried on my PC and error gone but div elements didn't flipped